# Jquery: Multiple name selector not working

Tags: jquery, html

Ey, I am testing some code I'm gonna use in my website. And I want to select multiple names in my jquery code. But it doesnt seem to work.

The idea is that people can only select 1 of both checkbox groups, but it only seems to use the code on the checkbox-1 group

my code:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-1" />
<input type="checkbox"name="checkbox-1" />
<input type="checkbox"name="checkbox-1" />
<input type="checkbox"name="checkbox-2" /><br>
<input type="checkbox"name="checkbox-2" />
<input type="checkbox"name="checkbox-2" />
<input type="checkbox"name="checkbox-2" />
<input type="checkbox"name="checkbox-2" />
```

JavaScript:

```
$('input[name="checkbox-1"], input["name="checkbox-2"]').on('change', function() {
   $('input[name="checkbox-1"], input["name="checkbox-2"]').not(this).prop('checked', false);
});
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/57tr36kv/2/

I have tried without the INPUT infront of the names but it still didnt do what its supposed to.

Comment: Why not use `type="radio"` for that and style it as needed? Also console throws `Syntax error, unrecognized expression: input[name="checkbox-1"], input["name="checkbox-2"]`

Comment: @justinas its weird because this works: `$('input[name="checkbox-1"]').on('change', function() {
   $('input[name="checkbox-1"]').not(this).prop('checked', false);
});`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is with selector `input["name="checkbox-2"]` - there should be no `"` before name:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[name="checkbox-1"], input[name="checkbox-2"]').on('change', function() {
    $('input[name="checkbox-1"], input[name="checkbox-2"]').not(this).prop('checked', false);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-2" /><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-2" />
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-2" />
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-2" />
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-2" />
```